# Algolia - JS Helper physical distance

Tags: search, geolocation, rank, algolia

Using Algolia's JS Helper for search, how would I retrieve a hit result's physical distance from the user's IP address?

In some of Algolia's libraries I see the Results object has a _rankingInfo property that contains the physical distance.  However, this property seems to be missing on the Results object when using the JS Helper.

I'm able to *rank* my results by distance with the following, but I can't actually see what that distance value is:

helper.setQueryParameter('aroundLatLngViaIP', true);
helper.setQueryParameter('aroundPrecision', 1000);

Answer (score 0):

There's a search parameter called [`getRankingInfo`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/getRankingInfo/) that you can use to retrieve those informations. By default its false, but if you're set it to true, it should be good.